# RegionManager for regions in floating windows

Tags: silverlight, prism

All the Prism 4 examples I've seen use Regionmanager to manage regions that arranged on some sort of layout.  I'd like the regions to be inside of [Floatablewindows](http://floatablewindow.codeplex.com/) (or something similar) instead, where they float over an ArcGIS Silverlight map control.

Is there some way to get RegionManager to do this?

If not, is there some alternative to RegionManager (like maybe, WindowManager) that I can use to manage floating (and ideally dockable) windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to generate floating windows for controls that are added to a specific Region. It is possible to do this. What you will need to make is a custom RegionAdapter for the container control that manages the dockable/floatable windows.